# Attempting to pick up an object that is relative to a player's position if it's near it using raycast (2D) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

So, I'm relatively new to C# and programming in general, I started one week ago. I've been looking into raycasting for 2D, and I'm wanting to make an object be removed if a player is near it and I press the 'E' key, this wil be for when I pick the weapon up.

This is working fine, however, it basically only works if I put the mouse over the object. I don't exactly want this, I want it to where if I'm close to the object, and I press 'E', it'll remove it. Something like a range.

Here's my current script:

```
    void Update()
    {

        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
            Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: so use the player position not the wordpoint of the mouse position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little error in the logic. Here's the docs for the function [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).

I'm going to assume you're trying to tell the direction with the mouse relative to the player so the code will look like this:

```
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(
     playerTransform.position,  // start raycasting from players position
     worldPoint - playerTransform.position  // in the direction of where the mouse is
     );

// some debugging code which will be excluded from build because of this condition 
# if UNITY_EDITOR
Debug.DrawLine(
     playerTransform.position, // start point same as ray
     (worldPoint - playerTransform.position) * 10 + playerTransform.position,  // end point = direction from start point * distance + start point
     Color.white,  // color of ray
     Time.deltaTime // duration
     );
#endif
```

Use the [`Debug.DrawLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) to see how the ray is being cast. If it's on the object but not colliding check Z-depth and layer mask. Maybe it's worth checking out some [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epZuI-YgXYo) as well.

Comment: Hey man, just thought I'd let you know that I just tried this and it's working perfectly in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into using the 2D player position and not ray casting. I know whenever I do this I use the players collider and put a check to see if the object has entered it.

```
Pseudo code could be something like this:
- Add collider set as trigger to your pickup
- Add some Pickup script to your pickup GameObject, it will hold the bullets count etc.
- When your player walks into a trigger, try to get pickup component from other object it collided with to see if it was a pickup.
- If it was, it has the Pickup component.
- Take the bullets count and add it to your player's weapon / bag / inventory
- Remove the pickup from scene
```

Comment: I actually did this before doing raycasting haha, I just thought there’d be a more nicer way of doing it. It might’ve just been my code but prior to ray casting it was just a bit messy. I’ll probably just revert back to using this instead if there’s no other way with ray casting, cheers for the help!